# Im new and i want to know how to create event in google calendar in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

this my code,
after execution no event added in my calendar,what im doing wrong?
thanks for help :)

```
function myFunction1() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ip');
      calendar.createEvent("my title",new Date ('27.01.2021'),new Date ('27.01.2021'));
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it follows the advice laid out in [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with your date parameters.

In Google Apps Script, *new Date()* only accepts date strings that are accepted worldwide. For example, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.

To fix your script, you can try this code below. This works successfully on my end.

```
function myFunction1() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ip');
      calendar.createEvent("my title",new Date ('2021-01-27'),new Date ('2021-01-27'));
  }
```

You can also specify the time by following the date format you are using.

### Reference:

[Everything You Need to Know About Date in JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, on this example if i want to use the way i wrote it, i must add YYYY.MM.DD, but how do you do it in my example?